# how to infer the result type from a function that returns multiple promise types

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a function that returns a Promise that can have two different types depending on the function parameters:

```
async function myFunction(buf: boolean): Promise<Buffer | string> {
    const bytes = "00";
    if (buf) {
        return Buffer.from(bytes, "hex");
    } else {
        return bytes;
    }
}
(async () => {
    // Sample 1 - works
    await myFunction(false).then((x: string) => {
        x.substring(0);
    });
    // Sample 2 - works
    await myFunction(false).then(x => {
        if (typeof x === "string") {
            x.substring(0);
        }
    });
    /**
     TS2339: Property 'substring' does not exist on type 'string | Buffer'.
     Property 'substring' does not exist on type 'Buffer'.
     */
    await myFunction(false).then(x => {
        x.substring(0);
    });
})();
```

Is it possible to infer the promise return type depending on the function's parameters so I don't have to explicitly declare or check them like I did in the first 2 samples?

Comment: Your sample 1 only "works" if you don't have `--strict` type checking.  If you turn it on then you'll see calls have the same problem.  To fix it you could give `myFunction()` a generic conditional return type, or overload it, or a combination of both, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mMjJlW).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current function type doesn't take into consideration the parameter value when defining the return type. So it doesn't matter what you send into it, you will always get back `Promise<Buffer | string>`.

To fix this, use [Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

```
async function myFunction(buf: true): Promise<Buffer>;
async function myFunction(buf: false): Promise<string>;
async function myFunction(buf: boolean): Promise<Buffer | string> {
  const bytes = "00";
  if (buf) {
      return Buffer.from(bytes, "hex");
  } else {
      return bytes;
  }
}
```

Comment: what if buf is optional like `buf:boolean = false`?

Comment: @voldomazta Add another overload that accepts 0 parameters